# Cloud Firestore How to subtract hour from Timestamp

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I am able to get the timestamp using this line in my index.js.

```
var now = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now();
```

I just want the timestamp that's 1 hour before now.

I've tried this and hasn't worked.

```
var old = now(now.seconds-1*60*60,milliseconds);
```

Also tried but it returns just the seconds instead of a timestamp

```
var old = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now().seconds - 1*60*60;
```

Any ideas on how to get the timestamp of an hour before?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firestore's Timestamp class doesn't offer the ability to do "date math".  You should do any date math using a native date type for your language, then convert that to a Timestamp when you're done.

Since you tagged this JavaScript, you could use a normal Date object to do the math:

```
const date = new Date(Date.now() - 60*60*1000)
```

The convert that to a Timestamp with [Timestamp.fromDate()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Timestamp.html#.fromDate):

```
const timestamp = admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(date)
```